# Css class design is not working to appended elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, append

[image] 
        [image]

Form the above two images css is not working when I append some html code with Jquery. Here is my html code:

```
<tbody id="strengthsTableBody">
<tr><td class='text-center'>
<div class="text-center">
    <div class="inline">
        <div class="easypiechart" 
        data-percent="90" 
        data-line-width="15"
        data-track-color="#eee" 
        data-bar-color="#5cb85c"
        data-scale-color="#fff" 
        data-size="100" 
        data-line-cap='butt'>
            <span class="h3 step">90</span>%
        </div>
    </div>                      
 </div>
</td></tr>
```

Some code I am appending with Jquery and make it as a string, but it is not working. Here is my append script:

```
courceResultsData = 
"<tr><td class='text-center'>
    <div class='text-center'>
        <div class='inline'>
            <div class='easypiechart'
            data-percent='90'
            data-line-width='15'
            data-track-color='#eee'
            data-bar-color='#5cb85c'
            data-scale-color='#fff'
            data-size='100'
            data-line-cap='butt'>
                <span class='h3 step'>90</span>% 
            </div> 
        </div> 
    </div>
</td>
</tr>";

$("#strengthsTableBody" ).append( courceResultsData );
```

If possible you can suggest any other these king of circle script or css

Comment: In the line `<tr>td class='text-center'>`is  a '<' missing. Mistake in typo?

Comment: Updated actually it is there in code while asking here it got missed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that piechart is created by javascript on page load so when you have this in starting markup it works, and when you add it with jQuery you need to trigger library yourself.

Comment: which library do you use? this https://rendro.github.io/easy-pie-chart/ ?

Comment: `$("#strengthsTableBody" ).easyPieChart();` try doing this after appending

Comment: Make jsfiddle with your code and then I will try to help you.